# Custom Fields - How can I remove the publish option for certain users

Tags: custom-field

I am trying to set updates to `Pending` vs. `Publish` for a new role I created called **"members"**. Is there a way to remove just the `Publish` option for these users? None of the user plugins I have tried work. They will set it to `Pending` for new posts, but not for editing the post. I need it for editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
function wpse_113057_hide_publish_buttons(){
 $cpt = 'your_post_type';// can be post
 global $post;
 if($post->post_type == $cpt && current_user_can('members') ){
  echo '
    <style type="text/css">
      .misc-pub-section, #delete-action {
        display:none;
      }
    </style>
  ';
 }
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'wpse_113057_hide_publish_buttons');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'wpse_113057_hide_publish_buttons');
```

I did not find a hook to do this with some PHP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great - Thanks for such a quick response I will give it a try. Where is the best place to add this?

Comment: probably in a functionality plugin or in the `functions.php` of your theme if you do not need to change theme in the next months.